# Download a torrent file through PHP

Tags: php

I'm creating a torrent platform (without tracker) and I have some problems while downloading the torrent from the server.

This is my part of the script:

`$fn = dirname(__FILE__) . "/torrents/$id.torrent";`
`header("Cache-Control: public");`
`header("Content-Description: File Transfer");`
`header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$tname.torrent");`
`header("Content-Length: ".filesize($fn));`
`header("Content-Type: application/force-download");`
`header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");`
`readfile($fn);`

When I download the torrent throught this file (download.php in my case), torrent is not valid bencoding.
What's the problem or what I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work...can't able to test as torrent links are banned in my country :-(

```
$file = "abc.torrent" 
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/sdfsdfs.torrent')
move_uploaded_file($content, '$file');
```

Comment: I think that wouldn't work. I'm using $_FILES to upload the file.

Comment: Anyway, if I download the file from the server through FileZilla (drag&drop file), the torrent is working. It is broken when I download it with the script above.

Answer (score 0):

`PHP` alone **cannot** download torrents, you may want to install [transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/download/) and use the [transmission api](https://github.com/kleiram/transmission-php) to manage and download torrents with `PHP`.

Comment: TBDev it's able to download torrents with bencode and bdecode. I tried with both. I decoded and encoded torrent, but no success

Comment: Torrent platform. FileList.ro is using it.